# How to Include xml files outside /res/xxx

Tags: android, xml

For instance, a common custom Dialog title bar (title.xml) is used by 10 projects.
Currently Google forbids to include xml outside /res/xxx, it must be put inside res/xx for each project.
Is there a way to include resource xml file outside default /res/xxx?
For example, include the xml file "C:/sourcecode/include/title.xml"?

Comment: Could you not put the common pieces into a single library that you then include into all 10 projects?  I've done this with code, but not sure about res files.

Comment: Hi brianestey, I have a LinearLayout (title.xml) for custom Dialog titlebar which will be used in all projects. This LinearLayout can only be set to Dialog as resource. I should put title.xml in my own library filefolder and include in each project.

Answer (score 0):

The Library Project (http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) can solve this problem. 10 app projects can make reference to the library project which contains shared codes and resources. One thing needs to be noted: the path of reference library project defined in project.properties of app project can ONLY be relative path such as "../xxx"; the absolute can NOT be resolved.